# Does Argo CD trigger only upon modification of the tracked folder?

Tags: cicd, argocd

When we set up Argo CD to track a folder in a repository, let's say my application repo has a deployment folder tracked by Argo CD, the question is: does Argo trigger only if the tracked folder is modified or any change to the repo will cause it to trigger?

Answer (score 2):

Argo CD cannot assume that changes in other directories won't affect an application's manifests. For example, a Kustomize application might reference a `../base` directory. So, by default, Argo CD will refresh the application on any change to the source repository.

If you know that Argo CD should only refresh on changes to certain directories, you can use [the `argocd.argoproj.io/manifest-generate-paths` annotation](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/high_availability/#webhook-and-manifest-paths-annotation) to limit refreshes.

Comment: Which one do you think is better, using dedicated repos for deployment or using deployment folders inside the application repository?

Comment: @Rabi ooh. Loaded question. :-) I like mono-repos, but there are a lot of opinions. A recent thread in CNCF Slack has some discussion of the pros/cons: https://cloud-native.slack.com/archives/C01TSERG0KZ/p1648670484408789